# When does there exist a convex polyhedron with given edge lengths?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $n = \ell_1 + \dots + \ell_k$ be
a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $n$. Then there exists a convex polygon with side lengths
$\ell_1, \dots, \ell_k$ if and only if all of the $\ell_i$ are smaller
than $\frac{n}{2}$.

**Questions:**

1. What is the corresponding criterion in $3$ dimensions,
   i.e. under which conditions does there exist a convex polyhedron with
   edge lengths $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_k$?
2. How many of the $p(n)$ partitions of $n$ do occur as lists of edge
   lengths of some polyhedron -- i.e. which are these values for small $n$,
   and what is asymptotically the proportion of such partitions among all
   partitions of $n$ when $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Note that you need two polygons to share the longest edge, so an edge of length n/3 or longer will be a deal breaker, and I imagine n/4 will present some challenges.  This suggests to me a fraction tending to 0 for the probability of a partition to be a length list of feasible polytopes.  For d dimensions, I think n/d is a similar obstacle, but am less sure.  Gerhard "Fractions, Now There's A Chance" Paseman, 2016.04.16.

Comment: to start simple: for the tetrahedron there is the Cayley-Menger determinant in addition to having all the face obeying the triangle inequality (which is not sufficient)

Comment: A related question covering the case of simplicial polyhedra http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574323/can-i-specify-the-edge-lengths-of-a-simplicial-polyhedron

Comment: I would expect that the number of partitions, that correspond to a convex polygon is asymptotically the same (up to a constant) as the number of all partitions, is this true? Then if you only consider prisms over convex polygons you already get a positive fraction of all partitions of $3n$ for the form $(p)+(p)+1+\dots+1$, where p is a partition of $n$ that corresponds to a convex polygon. @GerhardPaseman: I am not convinced that the fraction should be tending to $0$.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: For polygons you are obviously right. -- But your conclusion
for polyhedra does not seem to be correct: since we have
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p(n)/p(3n) = 0$, it seems
your construction of prisms does only work for a fraction
of all partitions which tends to $0$.
-- Or did I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: @StefanKohl I just wanted to make it more plausible that the fraction of all "edgy" partitions, i.e. partitions which are a length list of some polytope, might not tend to zero. The prisms allow are not enough, but they do give a positive fraction of all partitions of the special form described above. The tetrahedron already seems to give a positive fraction of all partitions into $6$ parts.

Comment: I thought so too, then I tried placing edges together. So far the idea that seems to be most inclusive is to take three edges at a time of not too dissimilar lengths and "tent" them over an existing triangle. If the partition piece sizes don't grow too fast, this seems to work, but one still has to figure out which partitions those are. If one goes the route of starting with faces with large numbers of sides, one hits a large number of constraints pretty quickly.  Gerhard "Building Such Polyhedra Is Hard" Paseman, 2016.04.19.

Answer (score 7):

Since I expect the answer for *all* combinatorial types of polytopes to be somewhat obscure, let me give an answer to the more simple question of what happens for the **tetrahedron**. We denote the six edges of the tetrahedron by $(x,y,z,a,b,c)$ and assume six faces the ones with edges $(a,b,c), (x,y,c), (x,b,z)$ and  $(a,y,z)$. The sextuple $(x,y,z,a,b,c)$ corresponds to such a tetrahedron if and only if

- $(a,b,c), (x,y,c), (x,b,z)$ and  $(a,y,z)$ satisfy the triangle inequality, and
- the Cayley-Menger determinant $$CM(x,y,z,a,b,c):=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
  0 & x^{2} & y^{2} & z^{2} & 1 \\
  x^{2} & 0 & c^{2} & b^{2} & 1 \\
  y^{2} & c^{2} & 0 & a^{2} & 1 \\
  z^{2} & b^{2} & a^{2} & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
  \end{array}\right)$$ is positive.

This would be a complete answer to your first question if you only asked for the tetrahedron.

So if you consider a partition $(p_1,\dots,p_6)$ of $n$, you have to say which of the $p_i$s correspond to which edge, or just check all permutations of the partition (so perhaps it would be more natural to consider compositions?!). In any case if you do this for the first few $n$, you get a sequence like this (if there is no mistake in my calculations):$$[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 9, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 24, 25, 32, 34, 40, 47, 55, 61, 70, 83, 91, 101, 117, 124, 148, 160, 181, 195, 225, 243, 270, 301, 327, 359, 396, 432, 473, 513, 566, 604, 668, 712, 782, 844, 913, 985, 1056, 1148, 1227, 1313, 1421, 1509, 1640, 1730, 1863, 1985, 2127, 2269, 2410, 2572, 2738, 2905, 3099, 3276, 3490, 3682, 3914, 4128, 4377, 4615, 4892, 5170, 5450, 5753, 6057, 6389, 6725, 7067, 7460, 7807, 8236, 8638, 9077, 9504, 10005, 10461, 10961].$$ 
Compare this to partitions into 6 parts:$$[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 14, 20, 26, 35, 44, 58, 71, 90, 110, 136, 163, 199, 235, 282, 331, 391, 454, 532, 612, 709, 811, 931, 1057, 1206, 1360, 1540, 1729, 1945, 2172, 2432, 2702, 3009, 3331, 3692, 4070, 4494, 4935, 5427, 5942, 6510, 7104, 7760, 8442, 9192, 9975, 10829, 11720, 12692, 13702, 14800, 15944, 17180, 18467, 19858, 21301, 22856, 24473, 26207, 28009, 29941, 31943, 34085, 36308, 38677, 41134, 43752, 46461, 49342, 52327, 55491, 58767, 62239, 65827, 69624, 73551, 77695, 81979, 86499, 91164, 96079, 101155, 106491, 111999, 117788, 123755, 130019, 136479]$$
If you plot these two, you get:[image: compare sequences]

For a better comparison, I take the fifths root of the values to get this plot (since we now that partitions into 6 parts roughly grow like $n^5$):[image: scaled comparison]

From these few values one might conjecture that the blue values also grow roughly like $n^5$, perhaps with a factor $(1/2)^5$ slower than all partitions into 6 parts.

Comment: Very interesting -- thank you very much!

Comment: The first 85 terms of the sequence are
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 9, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 
 24, 25, 32, 34, 40, 47, 55, 61, 70, 83, 91, 101, 117, 124, 148, 160, 181, 
 195, 225, 243, 270, 301, 327, 359, 396, 432, 473, 513, 566, 604, 668, 712, 
 782, 844, 913, 985, 1056, 1148, 1227, 1313, 1421, 1509, 1640, 1730, 1863, 
 1985, 2127, 2269, 2410, 2572, 2738, 2905, 3099, 3276, 3490, 3682, 3914, 
 4128, 4377, 4615, 4892, 5170.

Comment: I have computed these numbers with
[these](http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/problems/tetrahedra_with_given_edge_lengths.g)
[GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) functions.

Comment: Cool, I will update the post and the plots when I have calculated the first 100 values. I have the same values you have, at least up to n=67, where I also get 1730. For n=90, the value is 6725. I have used sage. Would it speed up your code if you calculate the determinant once symbolically beforehand and then evaluate the corresponding polynomial?

Comment: If it simplifies a lot, then maybe, otherwise rather not much.

Comment: Now I calculated the first 101 terms in the sequence.

Comment: Very nice! -- Do you have any idea how the criteria look like if we take a few more edges? -- In particular, does the approach with the Cayley-Menger determinant 'generalize' in some way, or are determinants of such kind completely useless once one has more than 6 edges?

Comment: @StefanKohl: I expect that some sort of generalization would work, but I am not quite sure how.